# Rotate <div> element but not <p> in it

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, hover

```
<body>
    <div class="circle"> <p>projects</p></div>
    
</body>
```

```
body {
    div {
      width:100%;
      max-width: 250px;
      height:250px;
      background-color:red;}
     .circle:hover {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color:yellow;
        transform: rotate(0.5turn); 
        transition:all .35s ease;
     }
     .circle:hover p {
    pointer-events: none;
}

}
```

Hi everyone,

totally new to html and css here and trying to experiment an idea but  can't figure it out

how to apply the hover effect only to the **`<div>`** element , but will not affect the **`<p>`** tag inside it?

the idea is that I need **`<p>`** in the centre of **`div`** and remain the same place (or upside down) while **`div`** is hovered

[idea visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwo1d.png)

Answer (score 1):

You don not need to rotate the element to achieve the result from your image.

First you can use `flexbox` properties to center the `p` inside your `div` and use `:hover` on `div` to change its border radius.

```css
.circle {
      width:100%;
      max-width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: red;
      transition: all 0.5s;

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}
     .circle:hover {
        border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: yellow;
     }
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <p>projects</p>
</div>
```